# Why express server receives front end data as undefined?

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I am currently working on social media mern stack react app. I am using node js and express as my backend services , also using mongoose to store my data and axios and redux thunk which connect the backend to the front end. Till now I had no issue recieving and sending data to the server. Right now I am trying to create search post get request ,base on a keyword the user entered. The issue with it, that when I am sending the keyword to the server instead of recieving the string it gets undefined value, like redux thunk not sending anything. I will be very thankful if someone could help me with that. I am watching the code over and over again and can't find out the reason for that.

**My post controller class(I copied only the relevant function):**

```js
import express from "express";
const app = express();
import Post from "../model/PostModel.js";
import ErrorHandlng from "../utilities/ErrorHandling.js";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import catchAsync from "../utilities/CatchAsync.js";
import User from "../model/UserModel.js";
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

export const getPosts = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = req.body.keyword;
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page || "0");
  const PAGE_SIZE = 20;
  const query = new RegExp(data, "i");
  const total = await Post.countDocuments({});
  const posts = await Post.find({ $or: [{ title: query }, { content: query }] })
    .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    .skip(PAGE_SIZE * page);
  if (!posts) {
    return next(new ErrorHandlng("No posts were found", 400));
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data: {
      totalPages: Math.ceil(total / PAGE_SIZE),
      posts,
    },
  });
});
```

**My api class(front end,copied only the calling for that specific get request):**

```js
import axios from "axios";
const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const API = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
export const getPostsByKeyword = (keyword, page) =>
  API.get(`/post/getPostsByKey?page=${page}`, keyword);
```

**Post slice class:**

```js
export const fetchPostsByKeyWord = createAsyncThunk(
  "post/getKeyword",
  async ({ keyword, page }, { fulfillWithValue, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.getPostsByKeyword(keyword, page);
      if (response.statusCode === "400") {
        throw new Error("There are no available posts");
      }
      const fetchData = await response.data.data.posts;
      const totalPages = await response.data.data.totalPages;
      return fulfillWithValue({ fetchData, totalPages });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response.message);
    }
  }
);
const initialState = { status: "undefined" };
const PostSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {},
});
export const postActions = PostSlice.actions;
export default PostSlice;
```

**Calling the backend:**

```js
dispatch(fetchPostsByKeyWord({ keyword, page }))
  .unwrap()
  .then((originalPromiseResults) => {
    console.log("thte " + " " + originalPromiseResults.totalPages);
    console.log("The data is" + originalPromiseResults.fetchData);
    setTotalPages(originalPromiseResults.totalPages);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

As you can see I have not copied the whole code, I copied only the parts that are relevants for the question.

Comment: You're doubling up on body parsing middleware. Don't do that. You don't need anything from `body-parser`, just `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers cannot currently send GET requests with a request body. `XMLHttpRequest` (which Axios uses) will ignore it and `fetch()` will trigger an error.

See also [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/283366) for extra discussion on why trying this might be a bad idea.

You should instead pass everything required in the query string, preferably via the `params` option so it is correctly encoded...

```js
export const getPostsByKeyword = (keyword, page) =>
  API.get("/post/getPostsByKey", { params: { page, keyword } });
```

and grab the data via `req.query` server-side.

```js
const { page, keyword } = req.query;
```

With vanilla JS, you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to construct the query string...

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({ page, keyword });

// XHR
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", `/post/getPostsByKey?${params}`);

// Fetch
fetch(`/post/getPostsByKey?${params}`); // GET is the default method
```

---

Your Axios instance creation could also be a lot simpler...

1. Axios is usually quite good at setting the correct `content-type` header, you don't have to
2. Your Express app isn't doing any content-negotiation so you don't need to set the `accept` header
3. Unless you're actually using cookies (which it doesn't look like), you don't need credential support

```js
const API = axios.create({ baseURL });
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I manage to fix it in minutes, with your solution. Can I write body instead of params an it's still work?

Comment: @Jogn1522 no. For one, Axios doesn't even have a `body` option, it uses `data`. And secondly, I thought I was pretty clear in that you **cannot** send a request body / data / payload with a GET request

Comment: Hey thanks, it is so wierd because with all of the second get requests it dies work