# React - axios fetching empty array

Tags: javascript, axios

I could not fetch the data using axios, despite fetching it succesfully through postman. Not sure why this is happening

Here's my function in react

```js
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:3001/tasks/";

const getDashboardData = async (setTasks) => {
  await axios.get(`${url}`, {
    uid: sessionStorage.getItem("uid")
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data);

      setTasks(result.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Web app side

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../layout/Layout';
import { getDashboardData, handleCreate } from './DashboardScripts';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => { getDashboardData(setTasks) }, []);

...
```

Here's my server side code

```
// Returns all tasks
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let uid = req.body.uid;
  await db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("tasks").get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      let tasksTemp = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        tasksTemp.push([doc.id, doc.data()]);
      });
      res.status(200).send(tasksTemp);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).send(error.message);
    });
})
```

Postman screenshot
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hnhp.png)

I'm not sure whether I'm writing the Axios request properly, or whether I'm calling it the function wrongly from the web app. I tried different ways of writing the Axios request to no avail

Comment: Axios doesn't have a `uid` option. What is that meant to be doing?

Comment: @Phil It's the user id passed as json body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why express server receives front end data as undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607186/why-express-server-receives-front-end-data-as-undefined). See also [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/283366)