# Pass data in body of GET request in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, httpclient

I am trying to use an API which is of **GET** type and it is expecting the data in body, not as  query parameter. I am using `Axios` as HTTP client but it seems `Axios` is not supporting body in **GET** request. Since the API is third party, I can not change it to read data from params or change the method to **POST**.

Is there any way to pass data in body using `Axios` or any other HTTP Client?

The same API is working with body when using with `PHP Curl`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46404151/4756341

Comment: react-native or browser?

Comment: Also, if the API is ElasticSearch (the only one I know of that actually attempts to support GET request bodies), they also support POST requests

Comment: @Phil from Browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why express server receives front end data as undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607186/why-express-server-receives-front-end-data-as-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Use ***data*** or ***params*** parameter of the GET according to your needs

[Refer the docs for all the parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api)

```
axios.get(< your request url >, {
  params: {
    custom_data : < Your Body here >
  }
}).then(...)
```

Also Refer

- [Send object with axios get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404051/send-object-with-axios-get-request/46404151#46404151)
- [Axios get in url works but with second parameter as object it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947650/axios-get-in-url-works-but-with-second-parameter-as-object-it-doesnt)

Comment: Axios with data will not work for GET request

Comment: API is expecting data in body, not in  params

Comment: Just to correct you , Axios with data will work . Refer the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api. Based on your requirement pass it in `data` or `params`

Comment: Please check GET, not POST

Comment: Please refer in the **Request Config** section in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api) if you want data to work , you have to use optional config. It will work even with the GET , use `method='get'` as shown in the example

Comment: It is clearly mentioned 'data' will work only with methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH' in the docs. Which optional config you meant?

Comment: Apologies, could you provide more information about the API you are using , what is it actually expecting in the GET request